# ERROR: Unknown configuration property 'quartz.datasource.default.connectionString'

Tags: quartz.net

New user to Quart.net

Using the sample configuration file contained in the download.

```
<add key="quartz.jobStore.dataSource" value="default"/>
<add key="quartz.datasource.default.connectionString" value="Data Source=BRN0VMMSDB77;Initial Catalog=dbQuartz;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add key="quartz.datasource.default.provider" value="SqlServer-20"/>
```

In my web page I am getting the following error when I try to run a quartz job.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

thx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this

```
quartz.datasource.default.connectionString
```

to this:

```
quartz.dataSource.default.connectionString
```

(the only change is the S)

Comment: actually needed upper case "S" on all of them.